# Make a question of this sentence

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs

For this sentence:

> This way we couldn't make him aware of the changes we've made in his home

How can we make a positive question to get listener's confirmation, with emphasis on the current condition or literally the "**This Way**" phrase?

May we use "**Do**"? :

> Do this way we couldn't make him aware of the changes we've made in his home?

Comment: That is a strange sentence.  I'm trying to think of a context where the speaker would be criticizing an approach and yet "owning it" by saying **this way** instead of **that way**. Perhaps if the speaker were explaining why the approach had been abandoned. Even so, **that way** seems the idiomatic choice.

Answer (score 1):

*This way* indicates an explanation of why something was done in a particular manner. So a question emphasizing that phrase would be looking for confirmation that that manner was chosen in order to achieve the intended effect (that he would be unaware of the changes).

Context may change my judgement, but as written I might conjugate to fit either the simple past tense of *couldn't* or the present perfect tense used in *we've made*. I would make it into a question as follows:

> **Did we do it** this way **so that** we couldn't make him aware of the changes we've made in his home?

or

> **Was it done** this way **so that** we couldn't make him aware of the changes we've made in his home?

Answer (score 0):

Since the verb here is `could`, you don't need `do` to form a question (your `Do this way`… sentence isn't correct English, sorry!) Just swap `We could` for `Could we…?`

> **Could we** make him aware of the changes we've made in his home, this way?

Shifting `this way` to the end of the sentence helps to emphasize this part of the question.

Another way that feels more natural:

> This way we couldn't make him aware of the changes we've made in his home, **could we**?